# how to insert space in jsf page through bean

Tags: jsf-2

I am working with JSF.

I want to insert a space before some text, But it is not working.

Ex: max_lenght =8 
The String is "120.00" 
The out put will become "  120.00"
But it is giving "120.00" only

I know that using &#160 ; we will add space, but i want to add through bean.

Java Code

```
this.without_health_insurance_total_amount_as_String = d.format(this.without_health_insurance_total_amount);
        if (this.without_health_insurance_total_amount_as_String.length() < max_lenght) {
            this.without_health_insurance_total_amount_as_String = append_String(this.without_health_insurance_total_amount_as_String, max_lenght);
        }
public String append_String(String source, int max_lenght) {
        for (; source.length() < max_lenght;) {
            source = new String(new StringBuffer(" ").append(source));
            System.out.println(source);
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="#{paymentreceipt.without_health_insurance_total_amount_as_String}" />
```

[image]

I am trying to print the amount to below format:

1,779.99
   220.01
2,000.00

So i am adding 3 spaces for 220.01 through backing bean(above code).

Comment: have you tried verbatim? http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_verbatim.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..No I didn't that, let me try...

Comment: No it is not working...

Comment: can you add a link to an image showing your screen?

Comment: No, my requirement is through bean i need to add the space in-front of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bean

```
private String with = "&nbsp;&nbsp;xxx";
private String without = "xxx";
```

In your xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputText value="Without spaces:"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{myMB.without}" escape="false"/>
  <h:outputText value="With spaces:"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{myMB.with}" escape="false"/>

  <p:commandButton value="Enter" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

gives me

[image]